# Creating a Trigger that creates a task for campaign member

Tags: apex, trigger, tasks, campaign-member

I'm attempting to create a trigger that fires when my custom field "Retreat Role", on a campaign member becomes "Prospect". Now when they become a prospect I want to create a task for the user, that reminds them to create a follow up after 5 days from the day the trigger is fired. I have found a similar trigger to what I am looking for, but I am by no means much of a coder. Now I'm not completely sure how to make it so that the due date (ActivityDate) on my Task is presented as 5 days after the date that my trigger fires. I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

```
trigger InsertCompletedCallTask on CampaignMember (BEFORE update) {
    list<Task> AddTask = new List<Task>();

    for (CampaignMember CM : Trigger.new) {

        if (cm.Retreat_Role__c == 'Prospect') {
            system.debug(cm + '---------AddTask---------' + CM.Campaign);
            AddTask.add(new Task(
                            Subject = 'Follow up with Prospect',
                            ActivityDate = date.today + 5,
                            WhoId = CM.Contact.AccountId,
                            WhatId = CM.CampaignId));

        }
    }
    insert AddTask;
 }
```

Comment: Tony, were you able to deploy this trigger? I have been having the worst time writing a test class for this and I would LOVE your guidance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_addDays) about things which you use.

```
 Date myDate = Date.newInstance(1960, 2, 17);
 Date newDate = mydate.addDays(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi simply use this below code if the error is related to Activitydate :

```
ActivityDate = Date.Today().addDays(5)
```

and always try to insert the list by checking the list size. For Example: `If(AddTask != null && AddTask.size()>0)` then insert AddTask